mkdocs: How to do annotation on a grouped code block
I have an md like :


Line 1 # (1) ```

1.  This is Line 1 of TAB-A


``` { .toml .annotate title="TAB-B" }

Line 1 # (1) ```

1.  This is Line 1 of TAB-B


That one is work as expected.
Now I want to to do it in content tabs

=== TAB-A
``` { .toml .annotate title="TAB-A" }

Line 1 # (1)
```

1.  This is Line 1 of TAB-A

=== TAB-B
``` { .toml .annotate title="TAB-B" }

Line 1 # (1)
```

1.  This is Line 1 of TAB-B


It didn't work like expected.
Content tabs work perfectly if I don't put anny annotations
and here is my mkdocs.yml
site_name: ZoneSync
plugins:
  - search
  - autorefs

markdown_extensions:
  - tables
  - attr_list
  - md_in_html
  - admonition
  - pymdownx.inlinehilite
  - pymdownx.snippets
  - pymdownx.superfences
  - pymdownx.details
  - pymdownx.highlight:
      #use_pygments: true
      line_spans: __span
      anchor_linenums: true
      pygments_lang_class: true
  - pymdownx.critic
  - pymdownx.caret
  - pymdownx.keys
  - pymdownx.mark
  - pymdownx.tilde
  - pymdownx.tabbed:
      alternate_style: true
theme:
  name: material
  palette: 
    # Palette toggle for light mode
    - scheme: default
      toggle:
        icon: material/brightness-7 
        name: Switch to dark mode

    # Palette toggle for dark mode
    - scheme: slate
      toggle:
        icon: material/brightness-4
        name: Switch to light mode

  features:
    - content.code.copy
    - content.tooltips
    - content.code.annotate

extra:
  annotate:
    json: [.s2]



So, kindly please tell me how to do annotation for code blocks inside content tabs.
Since it'll simplified generated html
Sincerely
-bino-

I would suggest you include mkdocs.yml in your post so we know the exact configuration of your MkDocs.

@RyanLuu thankyou for your suggestion. now it's included in my post.
